# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in jquery append

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am doing dynamic add rows in laravel here is my code. what can I do?
i attached the error in below
if I can come to this page it can show this type of error but I refresh the page the error is disappear

```
function add_button(id){
            html = '<div class="form-group" id="'+id+'_'+num+'" style="padding:20px;">';
            html += '<div class="col-sm-8">';
            html += '<div class="row">';
            html += '<div class="col-lg-4">';
            html += '<div class="input-group">';
            html += '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>';
            html += '<input type="text" name="value['+id+'_start][]" id="completed_at" value="" class="form-control startTime" autocomplete="off" style="width: 150px">';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div class="col-lg-4">';
            html += '<div class="input-group">';
            html += '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>';
            html += '<input type="text" name="value['+id+'_end][]" id="completed_at" value="" class="form-control endTime" autocomplete="off" style="width: 150px">';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div class="col-lg-4">';
            html += '<div class="input-group">';
            html += '<a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="$(this).closest(\'#' +id+ '_'+num+'\').remove();">Remove</a>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
            
            num++;
            $('#'+id+'').append(html);
        }
```

**but it shows errors like this**

```
VM3358:7 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Function.globalEval (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2:2538)
    at n.fn.init.domManip (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:3:17225)
    at n.fn.init.append (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:3:14908)
    at HTMLScriptElement.cb (jquery.pjax.js:792:19)
    at next (jquery.pjax.js:803:12)
    at executeScriptTags (jquery.pjax.js:805:5)
    at options.success (jquery.pjax.js:324:5)
    at j (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2:26925)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2:27738)
```

what can I do?

Comment: Can you provide an example of `id` and `num`?  If these contain `'` you'll probably have problems.

Comment: Pls try this $('#'+id).append(html);

Comment: i try but not working @Aro

Comment: i provide the id and num @freedomn-m

Comment: @sivan I just tested your code, and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: *I provide the id and num* - I can't see it in the question, can you provide examples **in the question**?   As noted above, your code, as provided and missing details extrapolated/guessed, [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/5t2pnu8c/).  You need to provide *enough* code (and data), in the question, to allow us to reproduce the issue.  See [mcve].